# Subscription name starts with XMS: instead of JMS: when using IBM.XMS unmanaged client for .NET 4.7.2

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

I have a client application which is connecting to a MQ Topic with a durable subscriber.

When creating my subscriber with the method `CreateDurableSubscriber(IDestination dest, string subscription);` of a MQ Session object, the client build it's own subscription name using this pattern :

> **X**MS:{Queue Manager}:{Client ID}:{Subscription}

But the server is expecting **J**MS instead of **X**MS at the beginning of that string.

Here is an example of code :

```cs
using IBM.XMS;

var connectionFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ).CreateConnectionFactory();

connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);
connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, "localhost(1414)");
connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channel");
connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QMGR");
connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.CLIENT_ID, "CLIENT_ID");

var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
var session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
var destination = session.CreateTopic("/THE/TOPIC");
var subscriber = session.CreateDurableSubscriber(destination, "SUBSCRIPTION");

connection.Start();
```

Which try to connect to a subcription named `XMS:QMGR:CLIENT_ID:SUBSCRITION`.

I'm using IBM.XMS.dll version 9.1.4 from `MQ_Client-9.1.4.0-IBM-MQC-Win64`.

I can't find any documentation or property to override this XMS value when the client builds that subscription name ... any clue ?

Comment: One side note, the leading `/` in your topic string creates a empty node, so if you wanted a topic string of `A/B/C` it may seem logical that it would be `/A/B/C` but the leading slash just means there is a empty node at the start.  In the end it only matters what the publisher is doing so if the publisher is using  a leading `/` then you would have to match it.

Comment: IBM MQ JMS java libraries create subscription names as you mentoined with the format `JMS:{Queue Manager}:{Client ID}:{Subscription}`.  Since XMS is only a JMS like interface, it does not seem like any issue that it is uses XMS in stead of JMS at the start.  The name is just a name, it does not impact the topic string you are subscribed to or being able to receive published messages.  Can you explain more what you mean by "But the server is expecting JMS instead of XMS".  Is this just a MQ Admin asking why it does not show XMS, or is there something that actually relies on that string?

Comment: There is no JMS or XMS way to specify anything other than the `{Subscription}` portion of the Subscription name.  The only other alternative would be to write MQ classes for .NET app (not XMS.NET) that would create a Durable subscription for you.  This could be either to a specific pre-defined queue, or possibly if you left it as a managed subscription you could inquire the SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.XXXX perm dynamic queue that is created.  On the XMS side you would then just consume from that as a queue instead of a subscription.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The configuration we want to achieve is to configure a subscription on the MQ server with a "provided" queue. Now that the MQ Admin have created the subscription with "XMS:", the client throw an error with ReasonCode = 2533 which means MQRC_DEST_CLASS_NOT_ALTERABLE. It seems that my client try to change the DESTCLAS from "PROVIDED" to "MANAGED" on the queue manager ... Again, I cannot find any property to specify the client to avoid that behavior ... All we want is the client to use the actual configuration on the QM and not creating some random queue. Thanks.

Comment: Then don't treat it as a subscription, just open the "provided" queue directly.  In other words, if the MQ admin is fine to manage the subscription to a specific queue for you, you can just open that specific queue and read the published messages, no need to "sub" since the admin already took care of it for you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? In any case what I described above in my last comment is something that we have done to prevent having a "random queue".  If the MQ admin is going to define the subscription ahead of time then why not just consume from the subscribed queue as a queue vs trying to resume the subscription?

Comment: Yes, we did as you told, we consumed the queue directly and it's working as expected. Thanks for your help!